# How reference count work?

Tags: ios, memory-management, retaincount

Suppose a test scenario

```
Employee *aObj = [[Employee alloc]init];
NSLog(@"Retain count is1: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)aObj));
Employee *bObj = aObj;
NSLog(@"Retain count is2: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridgCFTypeRef)bObj));
Employee *cObj = bObj; 

NSLog(@"Retain count is3: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)cObj));

 Then output is :
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is1: 1
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is2: 2
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is3: 3


Employee *aObj = [[Employee alloc]init];
Employee *bObj = aObj;
Employee *cObj = bObj;

NSLog(@"Retain count is1: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)aObj));
NSLog(@"Retain count is2: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)bObj));
NSLog(@"Retain count is3: %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef)cObj));

 Then output is :
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is1: 3
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is2: 3
 TestMemory[1949:62438] Retain count is3: 3
```

So I am getting two different outputs with the same code. Can anybody explain why its happening ?Please help me .

Comment: This will be useful for you... http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Fogmeister beat me to it!